# How to avoid using instance variables in modules?

Tags: ruby, module, architecture, instance-variables

I am sketching out how would CsvVerify module work. Is there a way to not polute class that will include the module with instance variables

Idea is inspired by [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) and goes something like this:

employee_csv_importer.rb (using the module)

```
class EmployeeCsvImporter
  include CsvVerify

  headers 'ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Title or Department',
    'Age', 'Native Language', 'Fluent in English?'
end
```

csv_verify.rb

```
module CsvVerify
  puts "included"

  def headers(*names)
    @config = Config.new
  end
end
```

config.rb

```
module CsvVerify
  class Config

  end
end
```

So how do I reorganize this to avoid polluting EmployeeCsvImporter with @config?

PS.
And why doesn't this even work now?
Why do I get this output from running employee_csv_importer.rb?

```
included
/data/gems/csv_verify/examples/1_employees.rb:6:in `<class:EmployeeCsvImporter>':
undefined method `headers' for EmployeeCsvImporter:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you start writing your functionality without `module` and `include` first. This helps shape out the structure, especially if you are new to Ruby.

The methods added by including `CsvVerify` are added as instance methods, not class methods. Therefore you have this `NoMethodError`.

Comment: def self.headers doesn't work either. So you recommend I make CsvVerify a class instead and make EmployeeCsvImporter inherit it? Also I am not new to ruby, but am to writing modules. Never found similar concept in other languages and have to master it some day.

Comment: you'd need to __extend__ your class with the module that provides the ```header``` method.

I suggest you first write out the full functionality of your class and then decide how and if you want/need to split it up in modules. .

Comment: ok extend works, thanks, but that means @config will be a class variable?

Comment: yes. You are configuring the headers from class level in ```EmployeeCsvImporter```. 

As said: I'd first write the whole functionality inside a single class to have something working. Then make it re-usable by extracting. Especially if you are new to this.